# Implementing get_multi on app engine memcache

Tags: google-app-engine, memcached, python-memcached

I was wondering if somebody could help. I'm using the blobcache module outlined in this post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5081502/memcache-1-mb-limit-in-google-app-engine)

This works fine but I'm looking to speed retrieval from memcache by using the [get_multi()](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_get_multi)
key function but my current code cannot find the keys when using get_multi

My current get def looks like this

```
def get(key):
  chunk_keys = memcache.get(key)
  if chunk_keys is None:
    return None
  chunk_keys= ",".join(chunk_keys)
  str(chunk_keys)
  chunk = memcache.get_multi(chunk_keys)
  if chunk is None:
  return None
try:
  return chunk
except Exception:
  return None
```

My understanding per the documentation is that you only need to pass through a string of keys to get_multi.

However his is not returning anything at the moment.

Can someone point out what i'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

pass it a **list of strings** (keys) , instead of a **single string with commas** in it.

```
get_multi(keys, key_prefix='', namespace=None, for_cas=False)
```

> **keys** = List of keys to look up. A Key can be a string or a tuple of
>   (hash_value, string), where the hash_value, normally used for sharding
>   onto a memcache instance, is instead ignored, as Google App Engine
>   deals with the sharding transparently.

[Multi Get Documentation](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/memcache/clientclass#Client_get_multi)